# FtpWebRequest over SSL/TLS on a FileZilla Server with "Require TLS session resumption on data connection when using PROT P" enabled

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssl, ftp, ftpwebrequest

My application targets .NET 4.6.1 and I try to use `FtpWebRequest` to connect to a FileZilla server using TLS.
However, when the option TLS session resumption is enable, the code below failed with

> 450 TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection

If I disable the option, the code works.
What is surprising is that the code worked until we need to reboot the server for update it !
We tried with SSL code using PHP and it works as well when the option is enable.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
        AddressOf myCertificateValidation)

' Set up the request
Dim ftpRequest As System.Net.FtpWebRequest =
    CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://myserver.mydomain.eu"),
        System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = True
ftpRequest.KeepAlive = False
ftpRequest.UsePassive = False

' use the provided credentials
ftpRequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyUser", "MyPwd")

' List the directory content
ftpRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

' Send the request
Dim ftpResponse As System.Net.FtpWebResponse =
    CType(ftpRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
```

I tried to set several parameters but it's always the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can connect to FTP using FileZilla or WinSCP, but not with FtpWebRequest or FluentFTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636482/can-connect-to-ftp-using-filezilla-or-winscp-but-not-with-ftpwebrequest-or-flue)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. You have to change the *ftpRequest.KeepAlive* to *true* in the code below and it does the job.

I checked so many parameter's configuration before finding the good one...

Hope this help.

Etienne.

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.limilabs.com/blog/ftp-tls-encrypted-data-connections-fail-ems

It seems a Windows update in October 2019 causes FileZilla Server to exhibit this bug, due to its use of an outdated version of OpenSSL (1.0.2.11).

As yet there is no ETA on a fix for FileZilla Server. A temporary, but not recommended, solution is to uninstall the Windows update.